# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require - Angular 2 RC4 + Karma + Jasmine + PhantomJS,

Tags: angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, require

I have managed to get to a point where I have a proof-of-concept working application with the following set up

ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 rc4

the app is working fine and all the Angular 2 bits are working.

I have then added Karma+Jasmine in order to get started with some TDD with Angular 2 before writing any serious business code i.e.

http://blog.rangle.io/testing-angular-2-applications/

My problem is with Karma+Jasmine(+PhantomJS).

When I write tests in TypeScript without using the Angular 2 stuff, then Karma+Jasmine works fine and at the console I get the list of passing or failing tests.

However, I have recently written a unit test for an Angular 2 component which makes use of a service. In the unit test I mock the the service.

Karma+Jasmine+PhantomJS output to the console is now

INFO [karma]: Karma v1.1.2 server started at...

INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency

INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS

INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require**
  at wwwroot/js/tests/quote/quote.component.spec.js:2

When I look at the transpiled code for a very minimal version of the unit test in which I just try to get Angular 2 to register the provider to create the mock and nothing else

```
"use strict";
var testing_1 = require("@angular/core/testing");
var quote_service_ts_1 = require("../../app/quote/quote.service.ts");
var MockQuoteService = (function () {
    function MockQuoteService() {
        this.quote = "Quote from the mocked test QuoteService";
    }
    MockQuoteService.prototype.getQuote = function () {
        return this.quote;
    };
    return MockQuoteService;
}());
describe("Test Quote Component", function () {
    var builder;
    beforeEach(function () {
        testing_1.addProviders([
            { QuoteService: quote_service_ts_1.QuoteService, useClass: MockQuoteService },
        ]);
    });

    it("should pass", function () { return expect(false).toEqual(false); });
    it("should fail", function () { return expect(false).toEqual(true); });
});
```

I see that bit where PhantomJS gets stuck on

```
var testing_1 = require("@angular/core/testing");
```

My tsconfig.

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/js"       
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings",
    "typings/globals",
    "typings/modules",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
]
```

}

I instruct TypeScript to transpile to ES5 and I assume this is why the unit test above makes use of the **require** object when Angular 2 in pulled into the picture.
The typescript for the unit test is the following.

```
 import {
    inject,
    // async,
    addProviders,
    // fakeAsync,
    // tick,
    ComponentFixture,
    TestComponentBuilder,
} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {QuoteComponent} from "../../app/quote/quote.component.ts";
import {QuoteService} from "../../app/quote/quote.service.ts";

class MockQuoteService {

    public quote: string = "Quote from the mocked test QuoteService";

    public getQuote() {
        return this.quote;
    }
}

describe("Test Quote Component", function () {

    let builder: TestComponentBuilder;

    beforeEach(() => {
        addProviders([
            { QuoteService, useClass: MockQuoteService },
        ]);
    });
it("should pass",
        () => expect(false).toEqual(false)
    );

    it("should fail",
        () => expect(false).toEqual(true)
    );

});
```

Here is my karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Aug 04 2016 15:44:51 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
     "wwwroot/js/tests/**/*.js"
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      '**/*.swp'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    //browsers: ['Chrome'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

PhantomJS cannot find require - ok I get it.

How do I tell PhantomJS via Karma where to find "require"?

Am I supposed to install something like

karma-requirejs

and then follow something like

https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html ?

Am I getting this right?

am I on the right path to get Angular 2 RC4 to work with Karma+Jasmine+PhantomJS (or other browser) and TDD?

Is it right that the unit test above is transpiled to JavaScript which reference require?

Frankly, I am a bit confused about how the whole thing should be properly set up and work together as there isn't a single clear recipe for this out there that I could copy from. I proceed by trial and error and try to figure out things as I go along step by step using as little as required to get the job done.

Last thing. Assuming that it is all right to tell PhantomJS where to find requirejs, I suspect the karma.config.js should then become something like the
following

```
// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
 ....some angular 2 references from the node_modules\@angular ????
 "wwwroot/js/tests/**/*.js"
],
```

is this correct?

What references to node_modules\@angular would I need (Angualr 2 rc4)?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you find some answer for it? I'm having the same issue here...